# Alternative to notify-send

Tags: notify-osd, notify-send

I have to change from notify-send because there is a bug when for example youtube is fullscreen on one screen causes my other screen not to display the notify-send popup.

Are there any alternatives to notify-send that works with multiple screens/fullscreen programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out by using the `-u` flag with the argument `critical` it will force it to show, a workaround.

```
notify-send -u critical foobar "foobar is a nice word"
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the accepted solution.